# Could any one explain how to run my Junit test into cmd?

Tags: java, command-line

I've tried many solutions to run my test code in cmd but no luck so far. It's running in IntelliJ. All test are passing but when I try to run it in cmd I have error org.junit does not exist.

What I have to do or add to run this code in command prompt as I have to submit into Git.

```
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Nikolay Stamatov
 */
public class HamsterBurrowTest {


    public HamsterBurrowTest() {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of size method, of class HamsterBurrow.
     */
    @Test
    public void testSize() {
        System.out.println("size");
        HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
        int expResult = 9;
        int result = instance.size();

        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }

    /**
     * Test of totalFoodUnits method, of class HamsterBurrow.
     */
    @Test
    public void testTotalFoodUnits() {
        System.out.println("totalFoodUnits");
        HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
        int expResult = 280;
        int result = instance.totalFoodUnits();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }

    /**
     * Test of feedHungryHamster method, of class HamsterBurrow.
     */
    @Test
    public void testFeedHungryHamster() {
        System.out.println("feedHungryHamster");
        Hamster hamsterNibbler = new Hamster("Nibbler", 50);
        HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
        int expResult = 60;
        int result = instance.feedHungryHamster(hamsterNibbler);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);

        int expAppetite = -10;
        int appetite = hamsterNibbler.getAppetite();
        assertEquals(expAppetite, appetite);

        int expTotalFoodUnits = 220;
        int totalFoodUnits = instance.totalFoodUnits();
        assertEquals(expTotalFoodUnits, totalFoodUnits);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFeedHungryHamsterSingleBurrow() {
        System.out.println("testFeedHungryHamsterSingleBurrow");
        Hamster hamsterNibbler = new Hamster("Nibbler", 50);
        HamsterBurrow instance = new DeadEnd(new HamsterFood(30));
        int expResult = 30;
        int result = instance.feedHungryHamster(hamsterNibbler);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);

        int expAppetite = 20;
        int appetite = hamsterNibbler.getAppetite();
        assertEquals(expAppetite, appetite);

        int expTotalFoodUnits = 0;
        int totalFoodUnits = instance.totalFoodUnits();
        assertEquals(expTotalFoodUnits, totalFoodUnits);
    }


    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testFeedHungryHamsterNull(){
        System.out.println("testFeedHungryHamsterNull");
        HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
        instance.feedHungryHamster(null);
    }

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void testFeedHungryHamsterRepl`enter code here`ete(){
        System.out.println("testFeedHungryHamsterReplete");
        HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
        instance.feedHungryHamster(new Hamster("", 0));
    }
}
```

This is the result in my Intellij
[image: This is the result in my Intellij]

The result in cmd

```
 javac -cp "junit-4.12.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:." HamsterBurrowTest.java
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
 import org.junit.AfterClass;
                 ^
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
 import org.junit.BeforeClass;
                 ^
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
 import org.junit.Test;
            ^
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:4: error: package org.junit does not exist
 import static org.junit.Assert.*;
                        ^
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test
      ^
   symbol:   class Test
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
     @BeforeClass
      ^
   symbol:   class BeforeClass
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
     @AfterClass
      ^
   symbol:   class AfterClass
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test
      ^
   symbol:   class Test
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test
      ^
   symbol:   class Test
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test
      ^
   symbol:   class Test
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
      ^
   symbol:   class Test
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
     @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
      ^
   symbol:   class Test
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
         ^
   symbol:   class HamsterBurrow
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
                                  ^
   symbol:   variable Coursework3Main
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expResult, result);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
         ^
   symbol:   class HamsterBurrow
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
                                  ^
   symbol:   variable Coursework3Main
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expResult, result);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
         Hamster hamsterNibbler = new Hamster("Nibbler", 50);
         ^
   symbol:   class Hamster
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
         Hamster hamsterNibbler = new Hamster("Nibbler", 50);
                                      ^
   symbol:   class Hamster
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
         ^
   symbol:   class HamsterBurrow
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
                             ^
   symbol:   variable Coursework3Main
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expResult, result);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expAppetite, appetite);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expTotalFoodUnits, totalFoodUnits);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
         Hamster hamsterNibbler = new Hamster("Nibbler", 50);
         ^
   symbol:   class Hamster
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
         Hamster hamsterNibbler = new Hamster("Nibbler", 50);
                                      ^
   symbol:   class Hamster
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = new DeadEnd(new HamsterFood(30));
         ^
   symbol:   class HamsterBurrow
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = new DeadEnd(new HamsterFood(30));
                                      ^
   symbol:   class DeadEnd
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = new DeadEnd(new HamsterFood(30));
                                                  ^
   symbol:   class HamsterFood
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expResult, result);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:83: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expAppetite, appetite);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
         assertEquals(expTotalFoodUnits, totalFoodUnits);
         ^
   symbol:   method assertEquals(int,int)
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
         ^
   symbol:   class HamsterBurrow
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
                                  ^
   symbol:   variable Coursework3Main
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
         ^
   symbol:   class HamsterBurrow
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
         HamsterBurrow instance = Coursework3Main.mkBurrow();
                                  ^
   symbol:   variable Coursework3Main
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 HamsterBurrowTest.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
         instance.feedHungryHamster(new Hamster("", 0));
                                        ^
   symbol:   class Hamster
   location: class HamsterBurrowTest
 38 errors
```

I checked every solution from this site and still no idea how to solve the issue

Comment: Please put the errors in a code block, not as an image.

Comment: Are you sure that jars are located in the directory from where you run your command?
You could copy command from Intellij console log and modify it to compile class instead of execute tests.